# Как показывать текст в MessageBox с новой строки?

Tags: c#, winforms

есть небольшой код в результате которого показывается messagebox,а как сделать чтобы какая то часть текста показывалась с новой строки?например в языке python с новой строки вот так:

```
("текст/n1.Новая строка/n2.Новая строка")
```

есть код:

```
if (textBox1.Text == "" ^ textBox1.Text.Length > 11 ^ textBox1.Text.Any(char.IsDigit))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Введите нормальное имя!");
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
MessageBox.Show("текст\n1.Новая строка\n2.Новая строка");
```

или

```
MessageBox.Show($"текст{Environment.NewLine}1.Новая строка{Environment.NewLine}2.Новая строка");
```

или

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("текст");
sb.AppendLine("1.Новая строка");
sb.AppendLine("2.Новая строка");
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```